# Two projects with common code

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I am assigned to two projects, both of which are derived from a common parent and targeted to be merged back to the parent around the same time.
To make it simple, let's call them master, projA and projB.

Let's say the folder structure of the source code is:
/src/main/UI
/src/main/backend

Let's say there is a file and we want to add a new common error handler inside of it.
This function should be shared between projA and projB.
/src/main/backend/common/errorhandler.cpp

The branching is as follows (both branched from master and ultimately merged back to master.
aN/bN are project specific changes.
AN/BN are changes errorhandler.cpp

```
       -- projA--a1-a2--A1--
      /                     \
------                       master
      \                     /
       -- projB--b1-b2--B1--
```

So at some point there may be changes in projA that are needed in projB, so the commits would look like this (say after cherry-picking A1 into projB).

```
       -- projA--a1-a2--A1--a3---
      /                          \
------                            master -- projA' -- projB'
      \                          /
       -- projB--b1-b2--B1--A1'--
```

From what I read, I cannot merge just A1 into projB.  It would merge a1, a2, and A1.

I could use cherry-pick, which would then be A1' in projB, at the expense having A1` and A1 being treated as separate changes when both projA and projB are merged back to master.

I was hoping someone might have a better plan where I could still use merge so that I do not end up with 'duplicate' changes.

Comment: I would say it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751373/git-projects-with-common-code

Comment: It's unclear why can't you merge, could explain more clearly?

Comment: @vince
Yes, it does look like the same issue, only they specifically called out two different projects vs two different branches.  I felt that was more of an issue on folder relationships, rather than the branching.

Though I call out two projects, the folder structure would still be:

/src
/src/code<br/>

Comment: @CharlesB
From what I read, a merge will merge all changes from the common point.  In this case, changes for ProjA specific files will be merged into ProjB, which is something that can't be done.

Comment: ok so what you want is that when someone changes some code in one file, some changes are common to the two projects, some are specific. Isn't it a bit complicated? I mean it's not a Git problem, it's a design problem. It means you want to have let's say a class that is customizable? Inheritance or composition are made for that. And I think even if it's different files inside a package, you can still have classes in one package inheriting from another one and split the packages in different Git projects/submodules. Is it what you want to do or I didn't get it at all?

Comment: @Vince
Yes, it's as you described it.  We already have split up the project specific items out.  The issue is to be able to make common changes and share them between projects.  Both projects are on parallel development timelines and both will be merged back to a common parent in the end.
I am concerned that since cherry-picks have no link to each other, it might causes merging problems (especially the auto-merge kind) in the end.  Otherwise, I would cherry-pick the changes from projA to projB and treat projA as the "main" tree.

Comment: See my answer below, it will give me more space for a clearer understanding

Comment: I am a bit tired right now (so I'll take a second look at it tomorrow morning), but to do what you drew, you just need to run "git merge B1" and then "git merge A1" from master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

First (just to make sure), your `/src/main/backend/common/` should be implemented in the master branch (and maybe edited in any branch).

Then you create your branches `projA` and `projB` from `master`. You work on projA branch on the UI, and at the same time on the backend in projB branch. No problem so far.

You have now A1, B1 commits in respective branches.

```
      ---projA -- a1 -- a2 -- A1 
     /                          
----------------------------- master
     \                          
      ---projB -- b1 -- b2 -- B1
```

And what you want is only A1,B1 but not a1, a2, b1, b2. Indeed I recommend cherry-pick. One bad thing (among others) with cherry-pick is that the history is not nice afterwards. But in your case, I don't see many (even any) other possibilities.

When you are on master branch (to switch: `git checkout master`), you run `git cherry-pick A1` (A1 being the commit SHA) and it will merge the UI commit 'A1' into master branch:

```
      ---projA -- a1 -- a2 -- A1    
     /                             
------------------------- master ---- A1'
     \                          
      ---projB -- b1 -- b2 -- B1
```

and then, still on master branch, you merge the backend commit 'B1' by running `git merge projB`. The result is:

```
      ---projA -- a1 -- a2 -- A1    
     /                             
------------------------- master ---- A1' ---- B1'
     \                          
      ---projB -- b1 -- b2 -- B1
```

And that should be it, your project on master branch now has the form you wanted. I'll think a bit more about it to see if other things are possible.

Comment: thanks Vince, I reworded the question.  I wished the issue was an inheritance based one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll probably end up having one person in charge of the cherry-picking to isolate mistakes with the call.

Comment: I added another diagram in my question showing an example where the cherry-pick would occur.  It would be projA into projB.